# How to solve unit resolution?

Tags: prolog, logic

How can I express unit resolution in terms of code? For example:

```
A1
-(A1 & A2 & A3 ... & An)
```

where - is Not, and & is the **and** operator.

The answer should be:

```
-(A2 & ... & An)
```

How would I write it, in prolog (or scala, or some other language) for example?

In my mind it should be some kind of function that does something like this:

```
def unitResolution(sentence1, sentence2, ... sentence_n) : result
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar problem occured to me recently. I posed it a little bit differently.
Lets assume we have a Prolog program. And instead of doing backward chaing (which
is input resolution) we would like to do forward chaing (which is unit resolution).

I did not yet fully implement it. But one could try the following. A normal
backward chaining rule looks as follows:

```
p :- q1, q2, q3, .., qn. /* backward */
```

Now a forward chaining rule, which makes unit resolution with the first goal,
simply switches the position of p and q1. Thus it would look as follows:

```
q1 :- p, q2, .., qn. /* forward */
```

You can then profit of Prolog predicate indexing to search for a match clause in
the resoluton step. Lets look at the resolution step with a unit r first in the
case of normal backeward chaining rule. Assume the unit r unifies with q1. So the
new clause would be:

```
p' :- q2', q3', ..., qn'. /* backward */
```

The apostroph indicates that the mgu was applied. Now we want our algorithm to
yield new rules in the forward notation. This would be:

```
q2' :- p',  q3', ..., qn'. /* forward */
```

Or in Prolog, assuming that the operator (,)/2 is xfy:

```
% resolution_step(+Unit,+TrickyClause,-TrickyClause or Unit)  
resolution_step(U,(U :- H, G, B),(G :- H, B)).  
resolution_step(U,(U :- H, G),(G :- H)).  
resolution_step(U,(U :- H),H).
```

Here you see how this could be used iteratively. I am using the predicate agenda/1, to hold the units. And the Prolog database to hold the tricky clauses, also the newly created ones. So the predicates that come into play must be declared dynamic.

```
iterate :-  
  agenda(U),  
  clause(U,B),  
  resolution_step(U,(U:-B),C),  
  (C=(P :- Q) -> assertz((P:-Q)); assertz(agenda(C))).
```

Now one has to do iterate as long as there are changes and avoid creating duplicates. Or avoid variants or subsumptions. If there is no more delta in the tricky clauses or if there is no more delta in the agenda, we can stop with our forward search. Of course we could also stop with forward search if a certain goal is found.

But now you see the problem with this single unit resolution step. The intermediate results are not only new units but also new non-unit clauses. So in practice I guess one would not implement single unit resolution step, but something that has become known as hyper resolution. Namely resolving a clause with multiple units so that a new unit is created.

Hyper resolution would simplify the management of the iteration. No intermediate non-unit clauses would need to be stored, and the delta could more easier be detected. Also new deltas could be computed based on previous deltas. Avoiding some redundant reevaluation of the forward rules. But in hyper resolution we loose the indexing advantage of our tricky clauses. So I am still waiting for an interesting proposal for a hyper-resolution suited Prolog representation of forward clauses.

Best Regards

Edit 10.04.2012:
Meanwhile I have found a way to do hyper resolution. It is based on converting a clause:

```
P :- A
```

Into a clause:

```
delta(X,P) :- A_new(X)
```

by means of clause expansion. Delta should compute in P the resolution result for when a new unit X has arrived. I did already a couple of successful experiments (* ) (* * ), but indexing has not yet been implemented. I have a concept for indexing based on moving out certain conditions on X to the head of the rule, but did not yet have time to implement it.

(* )
8 Queens via Unit Resolution
https://plus.google.com/u/0/b/103259555581227445618/103259555581227445618/posts/2q6nd6VbgZJ

(* * )
Earley Chart Parser via Unit Resolution
https://plus.google.com/u/0/b/103259555581227445618/103259555581227445618/posts/4tFbxLbknYe

Comment: Wow, ok... That is one long answer! Is this possible, perhaps, with another language - like lisp or scala? Or do you think prolog is useful here.

Comment: Actually it is pretty simple in Java, and thus should also be pretty simple in Scala. From my point of view is more difficult to do in Prolog. In an imperative language is more simpler to juggle around clauses and units, and even to build speedup structures, such as indexes.

Comment: Interesting, is there an implementation in Java (for example) somewhere?

Comment: There is a google project, which implements the algorithms of some AI text book. http://code.google.com/p/aima-java/ Maybe you find something there. They have also a resolution section.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to use the Prolog block directive to trigger unit-resolution.
There is a very nice article "A Pearl on SAT and SMT Solving in Prolog" by Howe & King on this technique along with source code at: http://www.soi.city.ac.uk/~jacob/solver/.
We use similar technique in the constraint solver of our ProB tool written in Prolog (if you are really interested you can find a recent paper here: http://www.stups.uni-duesseldorf.de/publications_detail.php?id=325).